# Can a Windows form proportionally resize all of its contents when the window is resized?

Tags: windows, forms

I have a few forms that have a somewhat complex arrangement of controls (written in C#). I want to be able to resize the window containing the form (at run time) and have the forms' contents all change size proportionally AND keep their relative positions.

I have done a lot of searching and have found lots of people talking about using the anchor property but this does not seem to work for me. If I anchor to all edges, the controls resize but start overlapping each other. I need them to keep their relative positions on the forms and get bigger/smaller.

Imagine resizing a photograph (of the form) on the screen, that's what I want to be able to do. What is the best way of going about that?

Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about C#/Winforms? Your question is a bit unclear, and doesn't show any code.

Comment: For anything more complex than a peanut, you'll probably want to incorporate the [TableLayoutPanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21wykkx(v=vs.110).aspx) container.

Comment: @Ransom what code do you want to see?

Comment: Does a TableLayoutPanel forces everything into an ordered grid? I don't want that to happen, I have an unordered (not grid like) arrangement of controls of differing shapes and sizes.

Comment: Controls may span multiple columns/rows.  With a little planning and foresight, you can setup complex layouts that don't look like a tic-tac-toe board.

Comment: @MarkRansom I am asking for new code, not asking to check my current code. What exactly do you want to see? There is nothing weird about my anchoring code, that is the accepted anchoring behaviour but it is not what I want.

Comment: If you say "I tried so-and-so but it didn't work", seeing how you used so-and-so would be useful. I haven't used C# much, but I've *never* seen overlapping controls. Are you simply trying to make the form so small that the controls don't fit any more?

Comment: Well this isn't a question about how I used anchoring, because I know that that is the wrong tool to be using. The overlapping occurs when the form is made bigger, the controls get bigger so that they are anchored the same distance from the form edges. Eventually the controls start to overlap because they are getting bigger "faster" than the form. Anchoring is not the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would handle the `Form.Paint` event of your form and adjust/calculate the size and position of your controls. This isn't the cleanest or simplest solution, so you really should try to get one of the built in layout controls to work if you can.

```
    Private Sub MyForm_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint

            Try

                'get height of title
                Dim titleHeight As Integer = RectangleToScreen(parent.ClientRectangle).Top - parent.Top

                'set paddingTop to height of title + height of menustrip(if you have one) + 10px(can be whatever you want) padding
                Dim paddingTop As Integer = titleHeight + parent.MenuStrip1.Height + 10

                REM Adjust controls sized to scale based on new form size
                PictureBox1.Size = New Size(CInt(Width / 4), CInt(Height / 2))
                PictureBox1.Location = New Point(CInt(Width / 4 + PictureBox1.Width / 2), paddingTop)

            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
            End Try
        End If


    End Sub
```

Obviously, you need to know the scale and location of your controls relative to the parent form so if the aspect ratio of the form changes your layout wont unravel. You should also consider having a minimum size for the parent form to avoid such issues. You can also handle the `Form.SizeChanged` to reduce the number of times the code runs, but I encountered scenarios where it did not suffice.